# pegar id de usuário private de uma sessão

Tags: php

Quero pegar um id de um usuário que está gravado na sessão,
estou tentando serializar o objeto quando criado:

```
$_SESSION['usuario'] = serialize($objUsuario);
```

e para recuperar tentei usar:

```
echo unserialize($_SESSION['usuario'])->getIduser();
```

retorna erro:

> Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "pojoUsuario" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition in

Se eu der um `var_dump($_SESSION['usuario']); die();`

retorna:

```
add-data.php:4:string 'O:11:"pojoUsuario":8:{s:19:"�pojoUsuario�iduser";s:1:"1";s:21:"�pojoUsuario�username";s:8:"nanous";s:18:"�pojoUsuario�senha";s:32:"1f32aa4c9a1d2readssdsdsdsddds6a04";s:18:"�pojoUsuario�email";s:20:"email@hotmail.com";s:25:"�pojoUsuario�frasesecreta";s:14:"dogs";s:21:"�pojoUsuario�resposta";s:4:"S#hu";s:17:"�pojoUsuario�flag";s:1:"1";s:22:"�pojoUsuario�datasenha";s:10:"2018-07-24";}' (length=398)
```

preciso pegar os dados armazenados na session, como nome do usuário e iduser e não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No arquivo que você está dando o `unserialize($_SESSION['usuario'])` precisa ter a definição da classe `pojoUsuario` também.

Uma dica é incluir o arquivo que define esta classe, por exemplo:

```
require_once 'PojoUsuario.php'; // inclui definição da classe

session_start();

echo unserialize($_SESSION['usuario'])->getIduser();
```

Mais informações e dicas na [documentação do PHP aqui.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.serialization.php)

Comment: Verdade, nao tinha atentado a esse detalhe.
Obrigado.